# MVC routing and url view helper

Tags: zend-framework2

I have a question regarding MVC routing.

I have setup my routes in module.config.php like this:

```
'router' => array(
'routes' => array(
    'album' => array(
        'type'    => 'segment',
        'options' => array(
            'route'    => '/album[/page/:page]',
            'constraints' => array(
                'page'   => '[0-9]+',
            ),
            'defaults' => array(
                'controller' => 'Trade\Controller\Album',                                       
                'action'     => 'index',
                'page'       => 1,
            ),
        ),
        'may_terminate' => true,
        'child_routes' => array(
            'default' => array(
                'type'    => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '[/:action][/:id]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
```

to have routes such as:

```
/album
/album/page/2
/album/edit/3
/album/add
```

In a view script, I use:

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->url('album/default', array('action'=>'edit', 'id' => $album->id));?>">Edit</a>
```

which results in

```
/album/page/1/edit/2
```

This is not what I want the url to look like. I want the url to look like 
    /album/edit/3

and since I was not providing a page number in the url parameter array, I wasn't expecting the default page to get picked up.

I am sure there is a smarter way to set up the routing needed and would appreciate any pointers.

Peter

Comment: Did you already try with `'page' => null` ?

Comment: Yes, I tried that but it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your route in **module.config.php** as follows

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'album' => array(
            'type'    => 'Literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/album',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Trade\Controller\Album',
                    'action' => 'index',
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                'add' => array(
                    'type' => 'Literal',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route' => '/add',
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'action' => 'addalbum',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
                'edit' => array(
                    'type' => 'Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route' => '/edit[/:id]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'id' => '[0-9]+',
                        ),
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'action' => 'editalbum',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
                'page' => array(
                    'type' => 'Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route' => '/page[/:id]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'id' => '[0-9]+',
                        ),
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'action' => 'pagealbum',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

Now change the link in your view script to

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->url('album/edit', array('id'=>$album->id)); ?>">Edit</a>
```

Your route will be now okay.

Comment: Thank you! That worked and is a good solution and practice because the exact routes are defined!